# How do I write to a web page instead of the console in C#?

Tags: c#

Currently, I am using the basic `Console.WriteLine("blah");` to write data to the console, but instead of writing to the console is there a way this data can be written to a web page? I've looked at other articles and documents on the Internet regarding my question, but have found no clear answer. Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Um, open your browsers console, and type in `console.log('test')`.  Are you really trying to write to a browser from a console application?  Please elaborate on what you're trying to do.

Comment: `but have found no clear answer` <= it would help if you started with a clear question. Example, it would be helpful to include from where this is executing. For example: if you are expecting a console app to write to a web page then you have a lot more reading to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This. It might be helpful `Response.Write("Blabla");`